# How to use /me to display my profile data in StackExchange API?

Tags: support, api, authentication, oauth2

So I'm able to use API calls like:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=30&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

to display a list of questions. This is easy as it doesn't ask for `accesstoken` with the request.

Now I decided to level up and fetch data related to the signed-in user. Of course it's going to ask an `accesstoken` to authorize the request.

How do I implement this using only JS + HTML code?

I know how to fetch the `accesstoken` once the user is authenticated using this:

```
    var = myAccessToken;

    SE.authenticate({
               success: function(data) {

                       myAccessToken =  data['accessToken'];
                       displayUserProfile('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow');
                            },
                            error: function(data) { console.log("OAuth Error!", data)  },
                            scope: ['read_inbox'],
                            networkUsers: true,
                          redirect_uri:'http://localhost:80/XMLHttpRequest/index.html'
    });
```

So this variable  `myAccessToken =  data['accessToken'];` now holds the accesstoken. But I don't know how to use it.

Should I do it like this?

```
function displayUserProfile(url) {

    const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('get', url, true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myAccessToken);
    xhr.responseType = 'json'
    xhr.onload = () => {

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log("success",xhr.response)
          }
      } else {
           console.log("fail",xhr.response);
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

The URL being passed is what's indicated in the [Usage of /me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) docs which is:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
```

wherein I get the error:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
>   400 (Bad Request)

In short, using the acquired `accesstoken`, how do I make a proper request to `/me` so I can fetch my private info (displayname, reputation, etc.) after signing in.

Comment: If anyone stumbles on the same error, just leave a comment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *read* requests, you must send the token (and key) in the URL. For example:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&key=dp55hR5Wr9UhOJReA6F2gg((&access_token=26nor26ZCVN4y5vn94Zg(w))
```

---

For *write* operations (EG [answers/{id}/upvote](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-answer)), you must use use HTTPS `POST` and then the `key`, `access_token`, and other parameters need to be form encoded.

---

Note that that doc page doesn't show you the full URL for security reasons.  (I only showed the above full URL after invalidating the token shown.)